# No FTP login prompt windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, ftp, iis-8

I've just finished installing windows 2012 fresh.   I setup the ftp service as I have in the past.  Now, however, when I go to a command prompt on another machine and type

FTP my.server.com

It says "connected" but no login prompt is presented and after a minute or so it says "Connection closed by remote host."

I am not sure what I missed in the setup.  I turned off the firewall to try, same results.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: All port forward correctly setup? tested it locally from the server ?

Comment: Disable Windows FW and test if the issue exists when it's disabled.... Re-enable the Windows FW afterwards if you've confirmed you can connect to the FTP service with it off and open up the TCP ports accordingly based on your FTP service configuration *e.g. FTP active vs. passive, ftps, etc.*

Comment: I can connect locally but when I try remotely it says "connected" but no login prompt.  I turned off firewall as I said with the same results.   I stopped the FTP server and tried to connect to see if the "connected" message still show and it doesn't.  It fails to connect.  It feels like a FW issue but its off and it still can't get a login prompt.

Comment: Have you enabled "anonymous access" to this site or your IIS setup configuration? Check in IIS. . . In the **Authentication**, select **Anonymous Authentication**, and then click **Disable** in the **Actions** pane perhaps.

Comment: Hi Magic, I am still trying to get back to this.  I have been migrating about 90 web sites.  I'll try your suggestion this afternoon

Comment: I still cannot get a login prompt.   The client connects and no login prompt is presented.  I've reinstalled the FTP service to no different results.   Anonymous is turned on now and it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I found was that a section was missing from the application.config file stored at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\  After adding the line in, the FTP server started prompting for logins.

```
<sectionGroup name="system.ftpServer">
<section name="log" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<section name="serverRuntime" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<section name="firewallSupport" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<section name="caching" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<section name="providerDefinitions" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<sectionGroup name="security">
    <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />

    <!-- the line below was missing -->
    <section name="authentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
</sectionGroup>
```